# Jetpack Compose collapse Bottom Sheet on outside click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I currently display a Bottom Sheet through a `BottomSheetScaffold` and want to collapse it when the user clicks outside the Bottom Sheet. Is there a way to detect the click outside of the Bottom Sheet?

This is the screen with my `BottomSheetScaffold`:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
            ) {
                Text("Hello from Sheet")
            }
        },
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
            topStart = Spacing.l,
            topEnd = Spacing.l
        ),
        sheetPeekHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp * 0.15f,
        sheetBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
    ) {
        Scaffold() {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                        } else {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                        }
                    }
                },
            ) {
                Text("Toggle Sheet")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is a visualization of the area in which I want to detect the click if the Bottom Sheet is expanded.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the `pointerInput` modifier with `detectTapGestures` to your `Scaffold`:

```
   Scaffold( modifier =
        Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) {
                        bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                    } else {
                        bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                    }
                }
            })
    }){
       //.....
    }
```

Comment: M3: isCollapsed = isVisible and collapse() = hide()

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using the `BottomSheetScaffold`, and I changed to the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` that already has that behavior by default.
I hope this could help anybody with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the answer with the last version of material 3:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(skipHiddenState = false))

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetContent = {},
    modifier =
    Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures(onTap = {
            scope.launch {
                if (scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
                    scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide()
                }
            }
        })
    }
)
```